# Correct heap implementation in a priority queue

Tags: java, heap

My issue is more semantic than functional, As the code does seem to implement the deQueue and enQueue functions correctly.

The reheapDown and reheapUp functions are being used incorrectly, And i believe the issue lies in my heap function

```
package priqueue;

public class Hosheap{
  private Patient[] elements;
  private int numElements;

  public Hosheap(int maxSize)
  {
    elements= new Patient[maxSize];
    numElements=maxSize;
  }

  public void ReheapDown(int root,int bottom)
  {
    int maxChild;
    int rightChild;
    int leftChild;
    leftChild=root*2+1;
    rightChild=root*2+2;

    if (leftChild<=bottom)
    {
      if(leftChild==bottom)
        maxChild=leftChild;
      else
      {
        if(elements[leftChild].getPriority() <= elements[rightChild].getPriority())
          maxChild=rightChild;
        else
          maxChild=leftChild;
      }
      if(elements[root].getPriority()<elements[maxChild].getPriority())
      {
        Swap(root,maxChild);
        ReheapDown(maxChild,bottom);
      }
    }
  }

  public void ReheapUp(int root,int bottom)
  {
    int parent;
    if(bottom>root)
    {
      parent=(bottom-1)/2;
      if(elements[parent].getPriority()<elements[bottom].getPriority())
      {
        Swap(parent,bottom);
        ReheapUp(root,parent);
      }
    }
  }

 public void Swap(int Pos1, int Pos2)
 {
   Patient temp;
   temp = elements[Pos1];
   elements[Pos1]=elements[Pos2];
   elements[Pos2]=temp;
 }

 public Patient getElement(int e)
 {
   return elements[e];
 }

 public void setElement(Patient p, int n)
 {
    elements[n]=p;
 }
}
```

The idea is to rearrange a simple priority queue system so when a patient object is removed, ReheapUp or down correctly rearranges the queue, Which the code does not accomplish. Should i also include the priority queue code, Or is this already too lengthy?

I am using NetBeans IDE 6.0.1, If that helps.

Comment: You can check out this simple but efficient implementation here http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=standardTemplateLibrary2#priority .

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage requirements, the answer relating to TreeSets will most probably do what you want.

However if you *really* need a queue, as opposed to a sorted collection, then the inbuilt [PriorityQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) may be of use.

Comment: As stated, It is a Priority queue i am looking to use.The only issue is correct detection of removed or added variables, And reheapUp or down being used to arrange the answers in a GUI

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question, but with Java you may want to look into the built-in Collection classes. You can get priority queue behavior but using a TreeSet (a type of ordered-set) and implementing a custom Comparator for Patient instances. Depending what you're trying to achieve, this may be preferable. It would look something like this:

In Patient.java ...

```
class Patient implements Comparator { 
...
public int compareTo(Patient other) {
    return getPriority() > other.getPriority() ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Then in the place you want to use the queue

```
Set<Patient> queue = new TreeSet<Patient>();
queue.add(p1);
queue.add(p2);
//traverse in order of priority
for(Patient p : queue) {
  doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Well..I have a for loop implemented to assign Priority rating and Name for each patient object in the Priority queue itself.I'm still looking for a simple way to do this, Without using treesets(Regretabbly, Not yet covered in my course)
Any other potential solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of a PriorityHeap.  I coded it up pretty quick so it may have some flaws but I have implemented the pushUp() and pushDown() logic.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Heap {

    private Double[] data;
    private int lastItem;

    public Heap(int initialSize) {
        // to simplify child/parent math leave the first index empty
        // and use a lastItem that gives us the size
        data = new Double[initialSize];
        lastItem = 0;
    }

    public void insert(Double d) {
        // double size if needed
        // should have a matching shrink but this is example code
        if (lastItem + 1 >= data.length) {
            Double[] doubled = new Double[data.length * 2];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, doubled, 0, data.length);
            data = doubled;
        }
        data[lastItem + 1] = d;
        lastItem++;
        pushUp(lastItem);
    }

    public void pushDown(int index) {

        if (lastItem > 1) {

            int leftChildIndex = index * 2;
            int rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;

            // assume that neither child will dominate (in priority) 
            // the item at index
            int indexToPromote = index;
            // there may not be a left child
            if (leftChildIndex <= lastItem) {

                Double leftChild = data[leftChildIndex];
                Double tmp = data[index];
                if (tmp.compareTo(leftChild) < 0) {
                    indexToPromote = leftChildIndex;
                }

                // there might not be a right child
                if (rightChildIndex <= lastItem) {
                    Double rightChild = data[rightChildIndex];
                    tmp = data[indexToPromote];
                    if (tmp.compareTo(rightChild) < 0) {
                        indexToPromote = rightChildIndex;
                    }
                }
            }

            // did either child dominate the item at index
            // if so swap and push down again
            if (indexToPromote != index) {
                swap(index, indexToPromote);
                pushDown(indexToPromote);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pushUp(int index) {
        if (index > 1) {
            // equivalent to floor((double)index/2.0d);
            // if item at index is greater than its parent
            // push the item up to until if finds a home
            int parentIndex = index >>> 1;
            Double parent = data[parentIndex];
            Double item = data[index];
            if (item.compareTo(parent) > 0) {
                swap(parentIndex, index);
                pushUp(parentIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    public Double removeTop() {
        // assume size is zero then examine other cases
        Double top = null;
        if (lastItem > 1) {
            // save the top item and take the bottom item and place it 
            // at the top the push the new top item down until it 
            // finds a home
            top = data[1];
            Double bottom = data[lastItem];
            lastItem--;
            data[1] = bottom;
            pushDown(1);
        } else if (lastItem == 1) {
            top = data[1];
            lastItem--;
        }
        return top;
    }

    public int size() {
        return lastItem;
    }

    private void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        Double temp = data[index1];
        data[index1] = data[index2];
        data[index2] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Heap heap = new Heap(4);
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            Double d = Double.valueOf(r.nextDouble() * 100.0d);
            heap.insert(d);
        }
        double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        while (heap.size() > 0) {
            Double top = heap.removeTop();
            if (top.doubleValue() > max) {
                System.out.println("bad ordering...");
            }
            max = top.doubleValue();
            System.out.println(max);
        }
        System.out.println("done...");
    }
}
```